# Firebase Phone Authorization Flutter Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, web-applications, firebase-authentication

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth

Is it possible to authorize users through their phone number using Flutter for a web app, and if so, how? I was thinking you might be able to use the JS package with Dart, but I am a bit stuck.

I know how to make firebase phone auth work for mobile, but I'm struggling to get it to work with web.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: number,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: codeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
 }
```

Comment: That call needs to happen to send a verfication code to the user, as explained here: verifyPhoneNumber But "I can't seem to fully grasp" is hard to answer. What isn't clear about the code? Is it why the call is needed? Is it one of the arguments? The more specific you can be about what you're struggling with, the more likely it is that we can help.

Comment: If there is no error message when you call the API, it is very likely that the SMS **is** being sent. If you don't receive it on your phone, that's a delivery issue that I'm not very well equipped to troubleshoot. But that topic comes up regularly: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+sms+otp+not+received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FlutterFire `firebase_auth` plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#-readme-tab-) says that it works on Android, iOS and Web. So that should work.

There's an [example of how to use the library](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib/signin_page.dart) that includes a [section on using Phone number verification to sign in](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib/signin_page.dart#L442).

Comment: I don't think it'll work for Flutter Web, you should take a look at [this](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth_web/lib/firebase_auth_web.dart#L355).

Comment: While the plugin supports Flutter Web, that method is not supported. The error thrown suggests you use `signInWithPhoneNumber` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use signInWithPhoneNumber instead of verifyPhoneNumber Because verifyPhoneNumber not supported for web... Here is i am sending you my code for your help (Note: RecaptchaVerifier is optional in my scenario it's not work without it)

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPhoneNumber(
    phone,
    RecaptchaVerifier(
      container: 'recaptcha',
      size: RecaptchaVerifierSize.compact,
      theme: RecaptchaVerifierTheme.dark,
    ));
```

If your code is still not working and if you have any query please check this [flutter web phone Auth](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/)

Comment: hey, thanks for this solution, can I know how to validate OTP for the same ??

Comment: can i use flutter phone auth code for flutter web just by changing verifyPhoneNumber  to signInWithPhoneNumber ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the issue of OTP not working in Firebase for Flutter Web.

I fixed this issue by following:

1. I used this method for flutter web.

   FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPhoneNumber();
2. Then I copied the script that you will get from Firebase while configuring the web app copy it in the web->index.html file make sure to run **npm install firebase** in root of flutter project.
3. Then copy this and put this in a script tag
   **window.flutterfire_web_sdk_version='9.22.1';**
4. Make sure to add FirebaseOptions for the web with all the necessary keys while initializing Firebase.

Now, when you re-run the web app it should work with a warning.

**Note:** I did try to set it up using Flutter Fire but it didn't work. the above solution worked for my case.