How to implement firebase mobile authentication for Flutter web for real phone numbers
I have implemented firebase phone authentication for flutter web and running the project in localhost but the issue I encountered is its working for test numbers but for real numbers its throwing error
Error

[firebase_auth/invalid-app-credential] The phone verification request contains an invalid application verifier. The reCAPTCHA token response is either invalid or expired.

and here is the phone authentication function
  static sendOTP(String phoneNumber, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      ConfirmationResult result = await auth
          .signInWithPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,
      )
          .whenComplete(() {
        context.read<WebAuthProvider>().updateOtpSendtoTrue();
      });
      printMessage("OTP Sent to $phoneNumber");

      context.read<WebAuthProvider>().updateConfirmationResult(result);
      log(result.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      throw Exception(e);
    }
    // return result;
  }

I tested it with test numbers, its working fine but for real numbers its throwing captcha error
How to fix it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60688890/14071053
